# how do you set text on JTextField that carries the java bean value after clicking submit

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

When clicking a JButton (submit) from one class another class is supposed to replace the text of a JTextField. The new text value is collected from a bean.  The new value appears on the console doing system.out.println but why doesn't it replace the value in the JTextField.  When the program is initially compiled the JTextField is initialize to what the current inventory read but once the user submits a new order the JTextField inventory is supposed to show the new inventory value. (subtracting the number of books ordered and the current inventory)

```
inventoryTextField.setText(String.valueOf(currentInventory));
```

Comment: Please post your code, it is unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I have been working with:

```
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            info.setBillingStreet(billingStreetAddressTextField.getText()); //This is to test the Edit menu item from the BookOrder class
            System.out.print(billingStreetAddressTextField.getText());
            info.setQuantityPurchase(quantityPurchaseTextField.getText());
            info.setCurrentInventory(Integer.parseInt(quantityPurchaseTextField.getText()));
            int n = info.getCurrentInventory();  //UPDATED VALUE
            inventory.createInventoryDetailsPanel(n);//PASSING THE UPDATED VALUE TO THE INVENTORY CLASS
        }
    });


 import java.awt.FlowLayout;  
 import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
 import javax.swing.JTextField;

 public class Inventory extends JPanel {

private JTabbedPane pane = null;
final JTextField inventoryTextField = new JTextField();

OrderInfo info2 = new OrderInfo();
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2;
JPanel panel22;
int currentInventory = 5000;
int n;

public Inventory() {
    JPanel componentsPanel = new JPanel();
    componentsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(componentsPanel,
            BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    componentsPanel.add(createInventoryPanel());
    add(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setVisible(true);
    mainPanel.add(componentsPanel);
    add(mainPanel);
}

public JTabbedPane createInventoryPanel() {
    pane = new JTabbedPane();
    pane.addTab("Inventory Details", createInventoryDetailsPanel(n));
    pane.addTab("Inventory Reordering", createInventoryOrderingPanel());
    return pane;
}

JPanel createInventoryDetailsPanel(int n) {
    panel22 = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel1.add(new JLabel("Item", JLabel.CENTER));
    panel1.add(new JLabel(" Java How To Program : Deitel and Deitel "));
    panel2.add(new JLabel("Quantity", JLabel.CENTER));
    panel2.add(inventoryTextField);
    System.out.print("Current Inventory is " + n);
    if (n != 0) {//THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING PROBLEMS TRYING TO PASS THE BEAN from the New Order class
                //SO THE NEW VALUE WILL SHOW IN THE TEXT FIELD FOR INVENTORY DETAILS. 
                //IT ALWAYS SHOWS 5000 NO MATTER WHAT (INITIALIZED ABOVE)
        inventoryTextField.setText(String.valueOf(n));
    } else {
        inventoryTextField.setText(String.valueOf(currentInventory));
    }
    panel22.add(panel1);
    panel22.add(panel2);
    return panel22;
}

private JPanel createInventoryOrderingPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField txt1 = new JTextField(10);
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel1.add(new JLabel("Item", JLabel.CENTER));
    panel1.add(new JLabel(" Java How To Program : Deitel and Deitel "));
    panel2.add(new JLabel("Quantity", JLabel.CENTER));
    panel2.add(txt1);
    panel.add(panel1);
    panel.add(panel2);
    return panel;
}
}
```